# Delete a link after log on

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am on the first steps to use MVC3, and in the newly created MVC web project, I have set up for a tab called Sign Up to locate next to Home, after I log on, I would like it to disappear but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @user1058271 what about the answers, which u got earlier, you need to accept it, rather than asking to get answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Razor`'s `if` statement to determine if user is authenticated:

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
   @if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
     <li>@Html.ActionLink("SignUp", "SignUp", "Home")</li>
   }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could test if the user is logged on or not in the view and display the link only if he is not logged in:

```
@if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("foo bar", "foo")
}
```