# Where in what file that stores registered user information in a newly created MVC web project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a post here [Delete a link after log on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240527/delete-a-link-after-log-on)
I have tried registering a user and log in successfully (what is the difference between Log in and log on, well, I use Log in to mean I am authenticated), I wonder where in what file of the project that stores the registered user information. That is because I would like to create a new database using SQL Server 2008 to store all registered users' information and other related things.
Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend what connection string and data provider you have configured in web.config. By default when you create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application it will use SQLExpress and create a database file in the `App_Data` folder. This file will be created when you register a new user and used after to login. Later when you want to switch to the full version of SQL Server all you have to do is to create the corresponding database (`aspnet_users` - using the [aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx) tool) and change the connection string in your web.config.

Or if you don't want to use the built-in schemas you could roll a custom membership provider.